# To show that $\mathbb R$ is the only non-empty clopen set in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Without using any notion of connected sets how can we show that $\mathbb R$ is the only non-empty clopen set in $\mathbb R$ ? ( actually I am proving that if $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function satisfying $|x-y| \le M |f(x)-f(y)| , \forall x,y \in \mathbb R $ , for some $M\in \mathbb R$ then $f$ is surjective by showing $f(\mathbb R)$ is clopen )

Comment: Let $\varnothing \neq U \neq \mathbb{R}$ be open. Show that $U$ is not closed. Consider $x\in U,\, y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus U$ and either $\sup \{ u\in U : u < y\}$ or $\inf \{ u\in U : u > y\}$.

Comment: Why avoid connectedness? You're basically going to walk through a proof of connectedness without using the word "connected."

Comment: @Neal: It's perfectly ok if I have to walk through a proof of connectedness without using the word "connected". Actually I want a basic proof from definitions

Comment: @DanielFischer: Could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varnothing \neq U \subsetneqq \mathbb{R}$ open. Pick $x\in U$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus U$. Suppose first that $x < y$. Let

$$z = \sup \{ u \in U : u < y\}.$$

Show that $z \in \overline{U}\setminus U$. Treat the case $y < x$ symmetrically.

Thus you have shown that any nonempty open set other than $\mathbb{R}$ is not closed.